# Finding the right complexity classes for functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to find the right complexity classes for these functions:
[image]

What I have so far is this. I will start from top to bottom:

[image]

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: ... but your answers appear to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your answers are correct, well done.

Comment: I thought bases don't matter in Big-O notation because they only affect by a constant factor. Or, am I wrong?

Comment: @gsamaras Thanks for clarifying!